# NSTableView: If i set "Row size style : Automatic " then all row have 0px size

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, nstableview

I have NSTableView. If "Row size style: Custom" (or small etc):

[image: Custom]

But if If "Row size style: Automatic" (i want dynamically row height sizing)

[image: Automatic]

Code of creating cells:

```
    extension ViewController: NSTableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, viewFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
        let currentOption = options[row] //options is Array of dictionaries

        if tableColumn?.identifier == NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "short") {
            let cellIdentifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "shortCell")
            guard let cellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView else { return nil }
            cellView.textField?.stringValue = currentOption["short"]!
            print(cellView.fittingSize.height)
            return cellView
        } else  if tableColumn?.identifier == NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "long") {
            let cellIdentifier = NSUserInterfaceItemIdentifier(rawValue: "longCell")
            guard let cellView = tableView.makeView(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, owner: self) as? NSTableCellView else { return nil }
            cellView.textField?.stringValue = currentOption["long"]!
            return cellView
        }
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your autolayout have a top and bottom constraint.

For example having object1, object2, object3 vertically, make sure that the object 1 is pin to the safe area/top of superview and object3 to the safe area/bottom of superview.

Answer (score -2):

You have autolayout issue. Check your constraints properly.

Comment: really? you thought that was helpful?